# Google charts combine line and candlestick chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-oauth

I have combine candlestick and line chart now i want to show annotations for values. is it possible to display that if so how to display annotation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.  Use a [ComboChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) with "line" and "candlestick" data series.  Use "annotation" [role columns](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) to annotate data points.